# Scala Testkit Unit Testing with Akka

Tags: scala, testing, akka, actor

I am using TestKit to test some of my classes for a Scala project I am working on involving Akka Actors, and I'm running into this issue:

`One or more requested classes are not Suites:  poc.PocConstituentsWatcher`

The class in question looks like this:

```
class PocConstituentsWatcher(_system: ActorSystem) extends TestKit(_system) with ImplicitSender with WordSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfter with BeforeAndAfterAll {
```

I didn't used to have this issue, because I had

`def this() = this(ActorSystem)`

but now I define my own ActorSystem via injection, so I have `val actorSystem = injector.instance[ActorSystem]` instead, and when I do

`def this() = this(actorSystem)`

I get an error saying it can't find actorSystem. I think it's because the constructor signature is incorrect? Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

Showed how to inject my actor system.

```
val injector = Guice.createInjector(new AkkaModule)
val actorSystem = injector.instance[ActorSystem]
```

In AkkaModule

```
object AkkaModule {
   class ActorSystemProvider @Inject() (val config: Config, val injector: Injector) extends Provider[ActorSystem] {
override def get() = {
  val system = ActorSystem("poc-actor-system", config)
  GuiceAkkaExtension(system).initialize(injector)

  system
}
  }
}

 class AkkaModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {

  override def configure() {
    bind[ActorSystem].toProvider[ActorSystemProvider].asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

Comment: ScalaTest and Specs2 require that your class have a default constructor (which is what you added with `def this() = this(ActorSystem)`. Off the cuff I can't think of a way of getting around this.

Comment: Hmm... So should I just include def this() = this(ActorSystem)? Will that cause me any problems? What is the default constructor used for? Alternatively I just redefined the method signature and it seemed to work...

Comment: You mention that you are using injection to define your ActorSystem. How are you injecting it? Do you have an example?

Comment: Edited to add an example.

Comment: Is this a compile-time or a runtime error?

Comment: The problem you might find is that your default constructor would use a different ActorSystem from the one you are injecting elsewhere. My question regarding compile vs runtime is that it makes no sense to me that the compiler would not find the `val actorSystem`. However, if it is happening at runtime, it could be because ScalaTest/Specs2 is not initializing the injector before calling your test.

Comment: Happening at compile time. I agree that it makes no sense! I think it is because the constructor of PocConstituentsWatcher doesn't take the type of actorSystem as an argument.

Comment: Pulling at straws here, but, could you try declaring the `val actorSystem` as a `lazy val`? Leaving everything as it was originally, including the `def this() = this(actorSystem)`

Comment: @MarioCamou didn't seem to work... Have no clue!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

`def this() = this(ActorSystem("poc-actor-system"))` which worked but is slightly worrying since technically the default constructor doesn't use the same actor system as the one I created `val actorSystem = injector.instance[ActorSystem]`. Will report back if anything breaks in the future...